# Saving foreign key field for linked model

Tags: python, django-models

I have models `Client` and `Requisites`. `Requisites` is OneToOneField for `Client`. No overwritten save methods and other.
I wonder when attribute `requisites_id` is set for `Client` objects.

```
c = Client()
c.requisites = Requisites()
c.requisites.save()
print c.requisites.id
>> 1
print c.requisites_id
>> None
c.save()
```

So field client.requisites_id is NULL in database.The funniest thing is that this code works fine:

```
c = Client()
c.requisites = Requisites()
c.requisites.save()
c.requisites = c.requisites  # how can this change something???
print c.requisites.id
>> 2
print c.requisites_id
>> 2
c.save()
```

Comment: Only if by "code works fine" you mean that it doesn't produce an error. This is pure guess, but the "=" operator could be redefined for the class Requisites, thus resulting in a change.

Comment: Yes I mean that requisites_id sets to 2 in database. But I have no idea why. May be I don't understand your guess but `=` can't be redefined in python.

Comment: Sorry I cannot be more precise, but wasn't there something along the lines of "setter" (and getter) when working with class property

Comment: Requisites is not a custom property but `models.OneToOneField(Requisites, null=True)`. How it is set inside django is the point of question.